# Why does numpy's `2**np.array([64])` produces 0, whereas plain python's 2**64 gives the correct result?

Tags: python, numpy, floating-point

It seems numpy's `2**np.array([64])` produces 0, which is a strange result. Why? I guess it has something to do with overflow, but feel unsure.

```
In [16]: 2**np.array([64])
Out[16]: array([0])

In [17]: 2**64
Out[17]: 18446744073709551616
```

Comment: Numpy arrays work with fixed size integers. The default integer type is 64 bit signed, as you can determine by looking at the `.dtype` attribute. The largest positive 64 bit signed integer is `2**np.array([63])-1`. This has nothing to do with floating point. If you had used a floating point constant, it would give you the correct floating point approximation. `2.**np.array([64.]) == array([1.84467441e+19])`